# Add different number for every row in a table

Tags: sql

I have a flat table with fake customer information (name, address, gender,...). I added a column to that flat table called customer_id where all of the values are null. Now I'm trying to add a different id for every customer but I'm not sure how to achieve that. This is what I've done so far, I don't have a primary key for that table since I want customer_id to be the primary key

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[add_id]
AS
BEGIN
    declare @customer_id int
    declare cursor1 cursor
    for
    select
        customer_id
    from
        flat_customer
    open cursor1
    fetch next from cursor1 into @customer_id
    while(@@FETCH_STATUS = 0)
    begin
        if(@customer_id is null)
        begin
            exec get_next_id_by_name 'Customer', @customer_id output
        end
        fetch next from cursor1 into @customer_id
    end
END
```

I'm still a beginning in sql so I'm not sure how to parse trough row by row

Comment: You haven't said what is wrong with the code you've posted? You can achieve this by creating a new empty table with customer_id as an identity column, then inserting the data from the existing table into it (excluding its customer_id column).

Comment: That is non-standard SQL. Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: I'm using SSMS my code does nothing more or less

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just do this:

```
DECLARE @i int = 1;
UPDATE flat_customer
SET customer_id = @i,
    @i=@i+1;
```